# serialize an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array as follows

`["http://wallpaper-gallery.net/top/wallpapers-6.jpeg", "http://wallpaper-gallery.net/top/wallpapers-8.jpg", "http://wallpaper-gallery.net/top/wallpapers-10.jpg"]`

I want to serialize it similar to `serialize()` method in jquery to get the following

`links=http%3A%2F%2Fwallpaper-gallery.net%2Ftop%2Fwallpapers-6.jpeg%0D%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwallpaper-gallery.net%2Ftop%2Fwallpapers-8.jpg%0D%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwallpaper-gallery.net%2Ftop%2Fwallpapers-10.jpg`

How can i achieve this in javascript in an efficient manner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

```js
var links = ["http://wallpaper-gallery.net/top/wallpapers-6.jpeg", "http://wallpaper-gallery.net/top/wallpapers-8.jpg", "http://wallpaper-gallery.net/top/wallpapers-10.jpg"];
console.log("links="+encodeURIComponent(links.join("\r\n")));
```